# What is the effect of configuring Encryption (as part of Amazon S3 and Gitlab) on uploaded files

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, gitlab

I am trying to set up automatic backups of Gitlab to AWS S3.

I have been following this set of instructions below to set up and configure a Bucket:

```
https://www.icicletech.com/blog/gitlab-backup-made-easy
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#uploading-backups-to-a-remote-cloud-storage
https://cloudkul.com/blog/automate-gitlab-backups-within-amazon-s3-bucket/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html
```

As of now, I have something like this (and it does seem to be working) in the  `gitlab.rb` file - but - I have a question about the encryption portion.

```
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
  'provider' => 'AWS',
  'region' => 'us-east-2',
  'aws_access_key_id' => 'my-access-key',
  'aws_secret_access_key' => 'my-secret-access'
  # If using an IAM Profile, don't configure aws_access_key_id & aws_secret_access_key
  # 'use_iam_profile' => true
}
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = ''
gitlab_rails['backup_encryption'] = 'AES256'
```

I also `enabled 256 Encryption within AWS` itself for the bucket.

I uploaded a backup from Gitlab to AWS. On AWS, the file has the following definition.

```
Owner 702261a042045906aab011fdadef768c
Last modified Dec 19, 2017 11:03:49 AM GMT-0600
Etag a6f04379656334c265d8fb5690185f0f-2
Storage class Standard
Server side encryption AES-256
Size 118138880
```

The server-side encryption was set within AWS itself.

So, my question is as follows:

When one specifies the

> gitlab_rails['backup_encryption'] = 'AES256'

in the `gitlab.rb` file, is this just a flag to use the encryption within AWS?
Or, is some kind of encryption taking place to the file locally before it gets to AWS (where it would be encrypted for a second time)?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I followed this here:
https://coderuse.com/2016/09/Configure-GitLab-Backup-Into-Amazon-S3/

and all seems to be working OK. When sending the file to Amazon, one can see that the file has been encrypted.

TIA